# How to HTTPS post in Android

Tags: java, android, https, http-post

I have looked at the following links, but nothing seems concrete.
[Secure HTTP Post in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253061/secure-http-post-in-android)
This one does not work anymore, I have tested it and there are comments from other people saying it does not work.

I also checked this out: [DefaultHttpClient, Certificates, Https and posting problem!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629122/defaulthttpclient-certificates-https-and-posting-problem?rq=1) This seems it could work but the blogger just leaves you hanging. More step by step instructions would be helpful. I managed to get my certificate by I have not been able to follow through his second step.

http://www.makeurownrules.com/secure-rest-web-service-mobile-application-android.html This one seem good, but again, I loose the author at the last step: "Back to our original rest client code." He too is all over the place, I have no clue which libraries he is using. He is not explaining his code and with the

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
```

it's another cliffhanger. Because that class has not been provided. So, if someone could explain how to do HTTPS post request in detail that would be great. I do need to accept the self signed certificate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I hope it would help. This is the code i used and worked perfectly fine.

```
private HttpClient createHttpClient()
{
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);

    SchemeRegistry schReg = new SchemeRegistry();
    schReg.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    schReg.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));
    ClientConnectionManager conMgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schReg);

    return new DefaultHttpClient(conMgr, params);
}
```

Then create an HttpClient like this: -

```
HttpClient httpClient = createHttpClient();
```

and use it with HttpPost.

Cheers!!

**EDIT**

And i did not used RestTemplate in my code. I made a simple post request. If you need more help just let me know. It seems like i recently have done something similar to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method i used for HTTPS Post and Here i used Custom Certificate, So change the HttpClient assignment with yours own...

```
public String postData(String url, String xmlQuery) {



        final String urlStr = url;
        final String xmlStr = xmlQuery;
        final StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();



        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                HttpClient httpclient = MySSLSocketFactory.getNewHttpClient();

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlStr);


                try {

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                            1);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xml", xmlStr));

                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    Log.d("Vivek", response.toString());

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream i = entity.getContent();

                    Log.d("Vivek", i.toString());
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(i);

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                    String s = null;


                    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {

                        Log.d("YumZing", s);
                        sb.append(s);
                    }


                    Log.d("Check Now",sb+"");




                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } /*
                 * catch (ParserConfigurationException e) { // TODO
                 * Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); } catch
                 * (SAXException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 * e.printStackTrace(); }
                 */
            }

        });

        t1.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println("Getting from Post Data Method "+sb.toString());

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: "This is the method i used for HTTP Post and Here i used Custom Certificate, So change the HttpPost assignment with yours own..." I need to work with HTTPS post not http post. Big difference.

Comment: And there is NO HttpsPost, but only HttpPost... So pls try it

Comment: This is no good, you should not be using thread like that, you should do this in background thread. How do you let the main thread know after T1 finishes?

Comment: Where do you deal with the self signed certificate?

Comment: Its a pojo, another java class, which has a static method which return the HttpClient. and Yes I need to make a correction, you must change you HttpClient instead of HttpPost. Its correct in the code

Comment: Dear its an Android Project, and this work is done on the NON-UI thread, keeping the UI 100% responsive. Any thread created in Android drops you off the Dedicated UI thread.